# Emacs plugin to browse Julia documentation, at point or textual

Tags: ess, documentation

It is quite annoying that I have to leave emacs to browse Julia documentation. Are there any nice plugins to get the documentation at point or that provides a nice direct textual interface to the Julia documentation?

Comment: I did not have the authority to add the Julia tag, if someone that is more entrusted in the community could do so for me it would be very appreciated

Comment: What is the format of the Julia documentation?

Comment: This appears to be part of [ESS](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia) already.

Comment: mark-down mode?

Comment: you may want to have a look at [`julia-repl`](https://github.com/tpapp/julia-repl)